# How to apply a fade transition effect to Images using a Timer?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, timer, gdi+

I am trying to make fade transition between two PictureBox Controls.
I used a Timer to change the opacity of two PictureBoxes using `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` every time the time elapses.

At this stage, the problem is that this code causes an exception:

> *System.InvalidOperationException: object is currently in use elsewhere*

I tried to modify cloned Bitmaps instead of directly operate on the Bitmaps set to the Image properties of the controls, but it doesn't work anyway.
Here is my code:

```
public Bitmap changeOpacity(Bitmap pic, int opacity)
{
    for (int w = 0; w < pic.Width; w++)
    {
        for (int h = 0; h < pic.Height; h++)
        {
            Color c = pic.GetPixel(w, h);
            Color newC = Color.FromArgb(opacity, c);
            pic.SetPixel(w, h, newC);
        }
    }
    return pic;
}

public void CrossFade(PictureBox pictureOut, PictureBox pictureIn, int duration)
{
    int outChange = 255; // opacity of pictureOut
    int inChange = 0;    // opacity of pictureIn
    int change = 55;     // change of opacity 
    fadeTimer.Interval = 10; // this timer's type is System.Timers.Timer
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureIn.Image);
    // make the pictureIn transparent first
    pictureIn.Image = changeOpacity((Bitmap)bmp.Clone(), 0);
    fadeTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => CrossFadeEvent(sender, e, pictureOut, pictureIn, outChange, inChange, change);
    fadeTimer.Start();
}

// being called every time interval
private void CrossFadeEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e, PictureBox pictureOut, PictureBox pictureIn, int oChange, int iChange, int change)
{
    if (iChange <= 255)
    {
        oChange -= change;
        iChange += change;
        textBox1.Text = iChange.ToString();
        pictureOut.Image = changeOpacity((Bitmap)pictureOut.Image.Clone(), oChange);
        pictureIn.Image = changeOpacity((Bitmap)pictureIn.Image.Clone(), iChange);
    }
    else if (iChange > 255)
    {
        pictureIn.Image = changeOpacity((Bitmap)pictureOut.Image.Clone(), 255);
        fadeTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some problem to fix here:

→ **`fadeTimer.Interval = 10;`**:
You're (possibly) using the wrong Timer: the [System.Timers.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer)'s [Elapsed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.elapsed) event is raised in a ThreadPool Thread. Unless you have set the [SynchronizingObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject) to a Control object - which is then used as the marshaller - referencing a Control in the handler will cause trouble (cross-thread violation exceptions).
In this context, you can use a [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer) instead: its `Tick` event is raised in the UI thread.
Also, the timer interval is too low. You end up with overlapping events.

→ **`GetPixel()`** / **`SetPixel()`**:
cannot be used for this task. These methods are too slow when called sequentially to set multiple pixels. They're used to modify a small set of pixels (or just one), not to modify the pixels of a whole image.
[Bitmap.LockBits()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits) is the common tool used to set the color bytes of Bitmaps.

→ **`pictureOut.Image = changeOpacity((Bitmap)pictureOut.Image.Clone(), oChange);`**:
You're using the Image property of a Control to provide the source Bitmap, then you're setting the same property that provided the source using the same source, modified.
This will never give you fully *faded* Image and you're looking for trouble.

There are standard tools that can be used to accomplish this task quite easily: the [ColorMatrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix) and [ImageAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imageattributes) classes. The former represents a standard 5x5 Matrix; the latter it provides methods that allow to set the values of the Matrix component.
The 5x5 Matrix component at `[3, 3]` (**`Matrix3x3`**) represents the Alpha value of all the `RGB` components.
The `ColorMatrix` class is applied to a Bitmap using the [SetColorMatrix()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imageattributes.setcolormatrix) method of the **`ImageAttributes`** class, which is then passed to the [Graphics.DrawImage()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage) overload that accepts an `ImageAttributes` object as argument.

Since this *Fade* procedure could be useful in other situations, I think it's a good idea to create an Extension Method: it adds a new **`SetOpacity()`** method to the Bitmap class.
It can also change the Gamma at the same time, should the fade effect require it.

What's left is to load two Bitmaps, create a Timer, set a *sensible* `Interval` (`100ms` here) and paint the Bitmap on the surface of two PictureBox Controls (three here, to test a simple blending effect ).

The Opacity increment/decrement value is set to `.025f`, so the opacity changes `1/4` of the `0.0f-1.0f` max range each second. To adjust as required.

---

[image: Bitmap Fade ColorMatrix]
<sub>The quality is reduced since the GIF animation can only use 256 colors</sub>

▶ Add the extension class to the Project.
▶ Setup a Form with 3 PictureBox Controls and assign the 3 event handles you find here to each of them.
▶ Don't assign a Bitmap to the PictureBoxes at design-time. The Bitmaps are loaded at run-time, as shown in the sample code.
▶ Add a Button to start the Timer.
▶ when the `fading` procedure terminates, you restart the Timer immediately, since it *rewinds* itself (the fading starts over, applying the inverse effect to each Bitmap and to the blended Bitmaps).

[image: Bitmap Fade and blend ColorMatrix]

Keep the Diagnostics Tools open: you'll see that you don't waste a single MB of memory, even if you repeat the operation multiple times.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class FormBitmaFadeTest : Form
{
    Bitmap sourceBmp1 = null;
    Bitmap sourceBmp2 = null;
    Bitmap fadeBmp1 = null;
    Bitmap fadeBmp2 = null;

    float opacity1 = 0.0f;
    float opacity2 = 1.0f;
    float increment = .025f;
    Timer timer = null;

    public FormBitmaFadeTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (components == null) components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        components.Add(timer);

        string image1Path = [Source Image 1 Path];
        string image2Path = [Source Image 2 Path];

        sourceBmp1 = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(image1Path)));
        sourceBmp2 = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(image2Path)));
        fadeBmp1 = sourceBmp1.Clone() as Bitmap;
        fadeBmp2 = sourceBmp2.Clone() as Bitmap;
        timer = new Timer() { Interval = 100 };
        timer.Tick += this.TimerTick;
    }

    private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        opacity1 += increment;
        opacity2 -= increment;
        if ((opacity1 >= 1.0f || opacity1 <= .0f) || (opacity2 >= 1.0f || opacity2 <= .0f)) {
            increment *= -1;
            timer.Stop();
        }
        fadeBmp1?.Dispose();
        fadeBmp2?.Dispose();
        fadeBmp1 = sourceBmp1.SetOpacity(opacity1);
        fadeBmp2 = sourceBmp2.SetOpacity(opacity2);
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        pictureBox2.Invalidate();
        pictureBox3.Invalidate();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (fadeBmp1 == null) return;
        var units = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(fadeBmp1, new RectangleF(PointF.Empty, pictureBox1.ClientSize), fadeBmp1.GetBounds(ref units), units);
    }

    private void pictureBox2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (fadeBmp2 == null) return;
        var units = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(fadeBmp2, new RectangleF(PointF.Empty, pictureBox2.ClientSize), fadeBmp2.GetBounds(ref units), units);
    }

    private void pictureBox3_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (fadeBmp1 == null || fadeBmp2 == null) return;
        var units = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(fadeBmp2, new RectangleF(PointF.Empty, pictureBox3.ClientSize), fadeBmp2.GetBounds(ref units), units);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(fadeBmp1, new RectangleF(PointF.Empty, pictureBox3.ClientSize), fadeBmp1.GetBounds(ref units), units);
    }
}
```

The extension method:
[Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

public static class BitmapExtensions
{
    static float[][] fadeMatrix = {
        new float[] {1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        new float[] {0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
        new float[] {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
        new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
        new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
    };

    public static Bitmap SetOpacity(this Bitmap bitmap, float Opacity, float Gamma = 1.0f)
    {
        var mx = new ColorMatrix(fadeMatrix);
        mx.Matrix33 = Opacity;
        var bmp = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        using (var attributes = new ImageAttributes()) {
            attributes.SetGamma(Gamma, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
            attributes.SetColorMatrix(mx, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
            g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
            g.DrawImage(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);
            return bmp;
        }
    }
}
```