# How to change the origin for rotation in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to rotate a picture box called player1 with the following command

```
  e.Graphics.RotateTransform(angle)

e.Graphics.DrawImage(BMP, New Point(-player1.Width \ 2, -player1.Height \ 2))

player1.Refresh()
```

However it seems to place the picture that i have drawn outside the picture box near the top left of the picturebox, i believe that is the current origin. Also, it only rotates about the origin located at the top left. **I would like to set the rotation point / origin of the picture box to the centre.** Thanks!

Comment: You're not rotating a PictureBox, you're trying to rotate the Image drawn in its graphics context. As mentioned before, use [Matrix.RotateAt()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.rotateat), it's simpler to handle. Remove that `player1.Refresh()` from there: you need to `Invalidate()` your PictureBox when the Mouse moves. You should mention the SizeMode of your PictureBox (in case it's `StretchImage` or `Zoom`).

Comment: See, for example. here: [Zoom and translate an Image from the mouse location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61964222/7444103). The TrackBar defines the rotation angle. See how much it takes to rotate that Bitmap, scaled and translated, using `Matrix.RotateAt()` (how many lines of code are needed in `canvas_Paint()` to generate all those *effects* -> `canvas` is a PictureBox).

Comment: Thank you for informing me about the Matrix.RotateAt() command. If i remove player1.Refresh() everything stops moving. Also, what do you mean by Invalidate() ? Thanks

Comment: Write `player1.Invalidate()`, put the caret inside the `Invalidate()` part and press `F1`. I also linked code that does just that in more than one place.

Comment: You really ought to have done a bit more reading on how GDI+ works. The `Invalidate` method is what tells the system what area of the control gets repainted on the next `Paint` event. The idea is that, when you want to change the drawing, you change the data that represents the drawing and then call `Invalidate`. A `Paint` event is then queued and you do the drawing in the event handler. If you want the `Paint` event raised immediately, you can call `Update`. The `Refresh` method simply calls `Invalidate` and `Update`. Why force a `Paint` event inside the `Paint` event handler?

Comment: Also, if you call `Invalidate` with no argument, you are going to repaint the entire control, which is inefficient. You should specify a `Region` or `Rectangle` that defines the smallest area that might have changed. That way, the minimum possible number of pixels gets repainted and that is more efficient. You can even call `Invalidate` multiple times with multiple different areas to keep the overall area as small as possible. You still draw everything in the `Paint` event handler but not all pixels will be repainted.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to set the rotation point / origin of the picture box to
> the centre.

Just use [TranslateTransform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.translatetransform?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Drawing_Graphics_TranslateTransform_System_Single_System_Single_) before you rotate:

```
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(player1.Width / 2, player1.Height / 2)
e.Graphics.RotateTransform(angle)
e.Graphics.DrawImage(BMP, New Point(-player1.Width \ 2, -player1.Height \ 2))
```

Depending on what operations you had done previously with `e.Graphics`, sometimes you have to `ResetTransform()` to put things back to the way they were at the beginning of the Paint() event before you Translate/Rotate/Draw.