# Zoom a picture with the drawings C#

Tags: c#, graphics, zooming

I want to create an application that will fill an area by giving it the points, I already did the drawing part but my problem is in zooming the picture. the user should be able to zoom the picture along with the drawings on it. so, I want a way to zoom in and out a picture and the drawings on it in C#.

I tried the ScaleTransform() function but it didn't work will because I couldn't get the real scale value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61964222/14171304