# Zooming a big bitmap in a picturebox in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, zooming

I am writing a modding tool having an interactive map.
[Image of the moddingtool and the map in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwnvo.png)
The map is movable via the buttons and the image should also become zoomable.
But I just cant figure out a way to zoom it without distorting and changeing the center.

My Code looks the following as of now:
ZoomButtons:

```
        private void ZoomOutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Vars.ZoomFactor <= 1)
            {
                Vars.ZoomFactor = 1;
                return;
            }
            // Decrease the zoom factor
            Vars.ZoomFactor /= 2; (*= 2 for the zoom in button)
            
            Vars.MainWindow!.Map.Image = UpdatePictureBoxSize(Vars.OrgMap!, new Size((int)Vars.ZoomFactor, (int)Vars.ZoomFactor));
            Debug.WriteLine(Vars.ZoomFactor);
        }
```

Update Map

```
public static Image UpdatePictureBoxSize(Image image, Size size)
{
    int newWidth = image.Width + (image.Width * size.Width);
    int newHeight = image.Height + (image.Height * size.Height);

    // Create a new bitmap with the desired size
    Bitmap resizedImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);

    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(resizedImage))
    {
        // Set the interpolation mode to high quality bicubic
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;

        // Calculate the source and destination rectangles
        Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
        Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

        // Draw the image onto the resized bitmap with the desired size
        graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }

    return resizedImage;
}
```

This will also need further performance improvements, but first of all I need to get it working.

Comment: [Zoom and translate an Image from the mouse location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61964222/7444103) -- Read the notes