# Disappearing to pictureboxes with effect

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a card matching game in c# windows form. When two cards(pictureboxes) are matched, I want to make an effect like rotation or fading as the cards disappear. How can I do it?

Comment: [How to apply a fade transition effect to PictureBox Images using a Timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61293719/7444103)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102241/how-can-i-add-moving-effects-to-my-controls-in-c/6103677#6103677

Comment: To do most kinds of fancy effects, you probably need to do [custom drawing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/custom-painting-drawing?view=netdesktop-5.0)