# Images slideshow with fade animation

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing a theater mode section in music player. The requirements is to loop through a folder containing images of any type(png, jpeg, gif) and show in a picture box with 5 seconds delay for images of type (png,jpeg) and delay time for gif should be the actual gif time duration. Also there should be fade transition between images when switch from one image to another in a single picture box. All need to be done when software is idle lets say for 60 seconds

**Problem**

> Currently the playing song directory has 'img' folder containing 3 png
> images and 3 gif.   The first attempt to read
> Helper.theaterImagesInfo.ToList() works pretty well

```
foreach (var img in Helper.theaterImagesInfo.ToList())
```

> It starts to display 3 png images with 5 seconds delay and gif images
> with the actual gif duration delay. but if i click picturebox to close theaterform as soon as the form is opened again after 60 seconds of idle state of software and loop continue
> to iterate again. The default image is shown with
> starting 2 png images from 'img' folder the 3rd png is skipped and then 4th gif starts
> to play for few seconds not the actual gif duration and continued in wrong order as well as incorrect delay, Seems like while loop is always running in background. therfore it becomes choppy.

**Desired Solution**
Whenever i play song theaterform should be displayed and start to show images from folder ( in the same sequence and delay) even if the theaterform is opened again after 60 seconds if the song is still playing. Also if there is a way to show fade when changing image in a single picturebox

**Code here**

**Program.cs**

```
internal static class Program
{
  public static Timer IdleTimer = new Timer();
  readonly static int miliseconds = 
  Convert.ToInt32(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60).TotalMilliseconds);
  internal static MainForm f = null;
  static public TheaterForm tf;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        MessageFilter limf = new MessageFilter();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(limf);
        Application.Idle += new EventHandler(Application_Idle);
        IdleTimer.Interval = miliseconds;
        IdleTimer.Tick += TimeDone;
        IdleTimer.Start();
        f = new MainForm();
        tf = new TheaterForm();
        var app = new MyApplication();
        app.Run(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs());
        Application.Idle -= new EventHandler(Application_Idle);
    }

    static private void Application_Idle(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IdleTimer.Enabled)     // not yet idling?
            IdleTimer.Start();
    }

    static private void TimeDone(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IdleTimer.Stop();

        if (MainForm.waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
        {
            if (!Helper.IsTheaterOpen)
            {
                if (Form.ActiveForm == f)
                {
                   Helper.IsTheaterOpen = true;
                   tf.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                   tf.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
                   tf.x = 1;
                   tf.ShowDialog(f);
                }  
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if (!Helper.IsTheaterOpen)
            {
                if (Form.ActiveForm == f)
                {
                    Helper.IsTheaterOpen = true;
                    tf.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                    tf.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
                    tf.x = 0;
                    tf.ShowDialog(f);
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}

public class MyApplication : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
{
    protected override void OnCreateMainForm()
    {
        MainForm = Program.f;
    }
    protected override void OnCreateSplashScreen()
    {
        SplashScreen = new SplashForm();
    }
}
```

**Helper.cs**

```
 internal class Helper
 {
     public static bool IsTheaterOpen { get; set; }

     public struct ImageInfo
     {
        public bool IsAnimated;
        public int durationInMilliseconds; 
        public Image ImageHere;
     }

     public static List<ImageInfo> theaterImagesInfo = new List<ImageInfo>(10);
  }
```

**MainForm.cs**

```
/*
 * Every song directory has one folder named img that contains images and gif relevant 
   to the song album
*/

  private int GetGifDuration(Image img)
  {
     int delay = 0, this_delay = 0, index = 0;
     FrameDimension frameDimension = new FrameDimension(img.FrameDimensionsList[0]);

     int frameCount = img.GetFrameCount(frameDimension);

     for (int f = 0; f < frameCount; f++)
     {
       this_delay = BitConverter.ToInt32(img.GetPropertyItem(20736).Value, index) * 10;

       delay += (this_delay < 100 ? 100 : this_delay);  // Minimum delay is 100 ms

       index += 4;
      }

     return delay;
   }

private void PlayAudio()
{

    // Getting images from folder and storing in struct on every song play
     if (Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(CurrentPlayingMusicUrl) + "\\img"))
     {
        var files =
        Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(CurrentPlayingMusicUrl) + 
        "\\img", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".png") || 
        s.EndsWith(".jpg") || s.EndsWith(".jpeg") || s.EndsWith(".gif"));

         Helper.theaterImagesInfo.Clear();
         foreach (var imagePath in files.ToArray())
         {
           using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imagePath))
           {
              if (image.RawFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Gif))
              {
                  Helper.theaterImagesInfo.Add(new Helper.ImageInfo { IsAnimated = true, durationInMilliseconds = GetGifDuration(image), ImageHere = Image.FromFile(imagePath) });
              }
              else
              {
                  Helper.theaterImagesInfo.Add(new Helper.ImageInfo { IsAnimated = false, durationInMilliseconds = 5000, ImageHere = Image.FromFile(imagePath) });
              }
            }

          }
       }
       else
       {
           Helper.theaterImagesInfo.Clear();
           Program.tf.x = 0;
       }
}
```

**TheaterForm.cs**

```
public partial class TheaterForm : Form
{
    public TheaterForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetDefaultImage();
    }

   /*
    * Getting Default image from top(root) directory ex. AllMusic. If no 'img' folder
      found in song album directory ex. AllMusic -> Justin Bieber -> (img folder not 
      exist)song1, song2, song3 etc.
   */
    private async void SetDefaultImage()
    {
        string path = KJ_Player.Properties.Settings.Default["MusicFolder"] + "\\img";
        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*", 
            SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".png") || 
            s.EndsWith(".jpg") || s.EndsWith(".jpeg"));
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                if(files != null && files.Count()>0)
                {
                    PictureBox1.Image =  Image.FromFile(files.FirstOrDefault());
                }
            });
         }  
     }
       
    public int x=1;
    private async void TheaterForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.PictureBox1.Image == null) SetDefaultImage();

        if (Helper.theaterImagesInfo != null && Helper.theaterImagesInfo.Count > 0)
        {
            while (x == 1)
            {
                foreach (var img in Helper.theaterImagesInfo.ToList())
                {
                    if (img.IsAnimated)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            this.PictureBox1.Image = img.ImageHere;
                            await Task.Delay(img.durationInMilliseconds);
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            await Task.Delay(img.durationInMilliseconds);
                            this.PictureBox1.Image = img.ImageHere;
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
                }
            }

            SetDefaultImage();
        }
    }
 
    private void PictureBoxTheater_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.x = 0;
        if (this.PictureBox1.Image != null) this.PictureBox1.Image=null;
        Helper.IsTheaterOpen = false;
        this.Close();
    }
```

}

Comment: You have too many `async void` methods and you `Task.Run()` code that directly set properties of Controls (hence, `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` set to `false`, which is *illegal*) -- About the Image transition + fading, see here: [How to apply a fade transition effect to Images using a Timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61293719/7444103)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you just need to [break](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/jump-statements#the-break-statement) out of that `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var img in Helper.theaterImagesInfo.ToList())
{
    if (img.IsAnimated)
    {
        try
        {
            this.PictureBox1.Image = img.ImageHere;
            await Task.Delay(img.durationInMilliseconds);
        }
        catch { }
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(img.durationInMilliseconds);
            if (this.x == 1) {
                this.PictureBox1.Image = img.ImageHere;
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
    if (this.x == 0) {
        break; // exit the for loop early
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't fix the issue. i have tried  
`if (this.x == 0) {
        break; // exit the for loop early
    }`

Comment: Seems to me like you should be creating a NEW TheaterForm instance in your Timer handler instead of re-using the previous one.

Comment: Yes, that fixed an issue. I actually had to create new theater form instance. Thank you