# c# Overlay multiple images with different opacity

Tags: c#, winforms

As of right now I can import multiple images from a folder, into multiple PictureBoxes that I can drag and drop, and I need to overlay them and make them fit together.
For that I would need a way to change opacity so I can line them up properly, similar to Photoshop layers.
Is there any way of achieving that?

Comment: How are you displaying the image on the form? Does that control have an Opacity property?

Comment: You'll have to combine [this Custom Control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51435842/7444103) (as you can see in the sample animation, it's translucent and it can overlap other Controls) with [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61293719/7444103) to change the opacity of a Bitmap. If I understand correctly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This would be easier in WPF